# Should a piezoelectric sensor be modeled as a voltage or current source?

Tags: sensor, piezoelectricity

I know that one can do source transformation between current and voltage source. But take a DC power supply, and we usually model it as a voltage source because the voltage is constant even the load current varies. One could model it as a current source though using norton equivalent but that doesn’t represent the battery as a first degree model imao.

So in reality is a piezoelectric sensor by its nature more close to a current or voltage source?

Comment: I think it’s most like a voltage source with a capacitor in series.

Comment: What @SpehroPefhany says is consistent with my experience building quartz-crystal oscillators and driving piezoelectric actuators.

Comment: It produces charge.

Comment: imao? Please don't use slang or arcane acronyms. I know IMHO and LMAO but what is imao?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson in my arrogant opinion

Comment: @ElliotAlderson .... If My Ass Opens...